# Pandas dataframe: find closest greater value in a row

Tags: python, pandas

I need to generate 5000 random values from 0 to 1 and for each **find closest greater value** of "sum" column and put this row in my new dataframe.

my old dataframe:

```
Probability  sum  
0.008773     0.008773  
0.008715     0.017488  
0.007244     0.024732  
0.006997     0.031730
```

So it will be new dataframe with 5000 rows from old one.

Comment: you want to calculate the cumulative sum of 5000 randomly generated values between 0 and 1. is this the question?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does your desired output look like?

Comment: for example: first random number 0.0199999999999 so i need select row with 0.024732 value of sum. And the same for next 4999 generated random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
## sample data
sudo = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u'''
Probability  sumt  
0.008773     0.008773  
0.008715     0.017488  
0.007244     0.024732  
0.006997     0.031730
'''),header=1)

# get sum values
sl = sudo.sumt.values.tolist()

# create random sample of 5000 values between 0 and 1
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'randoms': list(np.random.random(5000))})

# get closest value 
df['random_map'] = df['randoms'].apply(lambda x: min(sl, key= lambda y: abs(y - x)))

print(df.head(10))

    randoms     random_map
0   0.771321    0.031730
1   0.020752    0.017488
2   0.633648    0.031730
3   0.748804    0.031730
4   0.498507    0.031730
5   0.224797    0.031730
6   0.198063    0.031730
7   0.760531    0.031730
8   0.169111    0.031730
9   0.088340    0.031730
```

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you very much!